# Heats affect on material permeation?

Tags: materials, heat-transfer, temperature

I know that heat affects material permeation (increasing it); but I have not been able to find much in the way of data other than biologically, on how it effects materials such as plastics.

Does heat increase permeation exponentially, linearly, etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because diffusion processes go like e^kT, the apparent permeabililty will rise exponentially. The picture is a bit more complex than this for plastics, because they expand significantly with temperature, thereby lowering their bulk density and enhancing their permeability.